# VB.Net: Access Base class variable from derived class

Tags: vb.net

I was trying to see different ways i can access base class elements from the derived class. The first code that I wrote is shown below. It may be noted that the name Temp has been used multiple times: "Temp" is a variable in the base class, Temp() is a subroutine in the derived class. In this case I am getting an error in the statement `Console.WriteLine("Through Sub TEMP() in Class TWO: var = {0}", temp)`. In other words, I am not able to access the variable *temp* in the base class from the derived class.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim instance_two As New two()
        instance_two.Temp()
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module

Class one
    Public temp As Integer = 42
    'Trying to access this 
End Class

Class two : Inherits one
    Shadows Sub Temp()
        Console.WriteLine("Through Sub TEMP() in Class TWO: var = {0}", temp)
        'Error comes in above line under Temp.        
    End Sub
End Class
```

However when we change the name of the subroutine temp() in the derived class to something else, we are able to access the variable temp in the base class using the console.writeline statement in the derived class. See below:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim instance_two As New two()
        instance_two.Test() 'instance_two.Temp() changed to instance_two.Test()
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
Class one
    Public temp As Integer = 42
End Class
Class two : Inherits one
    Sub Test() 'Temp() changed to Test()
        Console.WriteLine("Through Sub TEMP() in Class TWO: var = {0}", temp)
        'Now the above statement works fine. Output is 42 as desired
    End Sub
End Class
```

Can someone please explain what is happening? Why is the compiler not able to access the variable temp = 42 in the first case and why things work fine when the name of the subroutine is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB.NET is case-insensitive and it doesn't require you to write parenthesis when you want to call a function.

So, for the compiler,  *Temp()* and *temp* are the same identifier for the function Temp() in the derived class.

Because you put the call to *Sub temp* into a parameter lists for WriteLine formatting expression, then the compiler tells you that *Expression does not produce a value* and cannot generate a valid executable.

A simple solution to keep the current situation is:

```
Console.WriteLine("Through Sub TEMP() in Class TWO: var = {0}", MyBase.temp)
```

Adding MyBase you explicitly tell the compiler what to look for.

[Microsoft Docs says about MyBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/me-my-mybase-and-myclass)

> The MyBase keyword behaves like an object variable referring to the
>   base class of the current instance of a class. MyBase is commonly used
>   to access base class members that are overridden or shadowed in a
>   derived class. MyBase.New is used to explicitly call a base class
>   constructor from a derived class constructor.